# How to append a search button inside a search input field using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a template, the name is Treble One Page Rsponsive Theme from Wrapbootstrap which uses Twitter Bootstrap. I am implementing the template and encountered this small error which drove me crazy.

There is a search bar, consists of `<input>` tag and `<button>` tag. Previously it was fine, until  I make it inside a `<form>`, the search bar started to act weird. The `<input>` field is centered, but the `<button>` appended into outside the  field making the whole things uncentered.

Here is the image, to be clear:

[picture](http://i57.tinypic.com/95svwl.jpg)

And here is my code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span8 offset2">
            <div class="input-append">
                <form method="get">
                    <input class="span5" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Search By Name" name="searchTerm" value="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary sicon-search sicon-white" type="submit"><i>Search</i></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your css and html code on jsfiddle or elsewhere?

Comment: alright I will do it, just a sec

Comment: @letalumil Sir, It seems impossible to post the code, because the style consist of many different class. well only one class is used but the other class also contributin to the element syle. Is there anything else I can do to make you see the problem? I am using a template, the original template which is now online is fine. it was also fine offline. It changes when I added FORM tag

Comment: Hey I spotted the problem, just now afte searching for days :D sorry and thanks for you help buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've googled this [template](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB089478D).

This code works on original template as expected:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8 offset2">
        <form class="input-append" method="get">
            <input class="span5" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Search By Name" name="searchTerm" value="Search" />
            <button class="btn btn-primary sicon-search sicon-white" type="submit"><i>Search</i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Main idea is to convert "input-append" div into form, instead of adding new form element within it.